# Bootstrap table pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, pagination

I am new to web development. For my web page development, first i came across JQuery, it was pretty amazing. Then i found a plugin for tables at https://www.datatables.net. That solved most of the data binding, searching and sorting.

But later when i discovered AngularJS for MVC development, I also found Bootstrap to go well with this MVC framework.

The question I have: are there any table pagination for bootstrap (3.3.5 preferably) ? Because i prefer to use AngularJS for binding, filtering and sorting?

Answer (score 2):

//Updated the link.
You can use bootstrap table:-
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [ui-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid) if you are looking for something with similar functionality to datatables (though ui-grid has many more features). UI-Grid can be customized to fit the Bootstrap theme. [The relevant section to pagination can be found here.](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination)

There's also [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) if you are just looking for some pagination components within the bootstrap template that play nice with AngularJS.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use Smart Table ref:-

http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/